# How to let Cmake Install to link my executables to my target shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with both target shared libraries and target executables. Using a minimal example for illustration purpose, the layout is as following:

```
project
    bin
    lib
    build
    CMakeList.txt
    foo
        CMakeList.txt 
        foo.hpp
        foo.cpp
    test_foo
        CMakeList.txt
        test_foo.cpp
```

Subdirectory `foo` creates a shared library `foo.so`. Subdirectory `test_foo` creates an executable `test_foo`, which is linked against `foo` in the build tree. The build is successful. However during installation I can not figure out how to install `foo.so` to `lib`, `test_foo` to `bin`, while having `bin/test_foo` linked against `lib/foo.so`. I used the install command:

```
install(TARGETS foo LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
install(TARGETS foo_test RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

in the respective subdirectory `CMakeList.txt` of `foo` and `test_foo`. `foo.so` appeared in `lib` and `test_foo` appeared in `bin`. However `bin/test_foo` is not linked to `lib/foo.so`. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: "However `bin/test_foo` is not linked to `lib/foo.so`." - What do you mean by "not linked"? Have you got some error? When?

Comment: There's no error from Cmake. But `ldd bin/test_foo` shows `libfoo.so` as not found. Executing `bin/test_foo` fails with  `error while loading shared libraries:  No such file or directory`.

Comment: So, you actually have your executable **linked** with the library (otherwise `ldd` won't show the corresponded entry at all). What do you miss is a **RPATH** adjustment. RPATH mechanism helps to locate linked libraries at runtime. See that wiki page about handling of RPATH in CMake: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, `RPATH` is indeed the reason. Setting it accordingly solves the issue.